# Printing customer order notes on invoice PDF

Tags: php, magento, pdf-generation, gomage

I'm having difficulty retrieving the customer order notes on an order. For example in Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php, there is a piece of code that works with a Sales/Order model. i.e.

```
($order instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Order) is true in the PDF example
```

or

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderID); in another example
```

During our checkout process, the customer is able to put in a comment for the order, but I don't know how to retrieve this. Does does anyone how to pull this? I'm looking for somewhere along the line of.. `$order->getOrderComments()`.

Edition: Magento Entreprise 1.11.2.0

Extension in use that allows order comment: GoMage LightCheckout 3.2

Comment: Which version of Magento are you using? Any extensions?

Comment: @nachito: thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my post. Please take a look. I *think* the order comment was not available prior to this extension. I've contacted GoMage as well, so I'll post an update if I find out for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the GoMage LightCheckout module extends `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` with a method `getGomageCheckoutCustomerComment()` which *should* give you want you want.

Source: http://wiki.gomage.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=590188

Comment: That's is superb! Thank you. I should have started out at the FAQ, hah. I was just going through the guide portion of this documentation.